# Java - csv read and rewrite part error - where to set cmd part 3?

Tags: java, excel, csv

There is an Error, that part 3 needs to get set on another line.
I am unable to locate the cuase of my mistake.
Where do I need to set the part3 line to overcome this issue?

```
import java.io.*;                      

public class javadruckdruckextended {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //scanning
        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("fax_user.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Druckausgabe123.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
        String textnow = br.readLine ();
        String n = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while (textnow !=null) {
            //Umlaute gegen ae,oe,ue tauschen
            String text = textnow;          
            String textXreplaced = text;
            textXreplaced = text.replace ("ä","ae");
            String textXXreplaced = textXreplaced;
            textXXreplaced = textXreplaced.replace ("ü","ue");
            String textXXXreplaced = textXXreplaced;
            textXXXreplaced = textXXreplaced.replace ("ö","oe");
            String textXXXXreplaced = textXXXreplaced.replace("ß","ss");
            textXXXXreplaced = textXXXreplaced;

            //Text umformatieren, splitten, E-Mail, Nummer anhängen
            String textreplaced = textXXXXreplaced.replace(" ", "");
            String textreplacedtwo = textreplaced.replace("\"","");
            String textreplacedthree = textreplacedtwo.replace(";","");
            String textreplacedfour = textreplacedthree.replace(".",","); // Um das "Dr." bei Friedbert Maas wegzusplitten. 

            String [] parts = textreplacedfour.split(",");

            /* Zur Fehlerkontrolle  
             *  if (parts.length<3) { System.out.println(textnow);}
             * else { 
             */      
             String Email = "@bogestra.de";                      
             String Zahlen = ";3";                                
             String part1 = parts[0];                           
             String part2 = parts[1];                  
             String part3 = parts[2];

             if (parts.length < 2){ 
                 String Sonderfalleins = part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
                 bw.write (Sonderfalleins);  
             } //close if
             else {
                 if  (parts.length > 3) {
                     String part4 = parts[3]; 
                     String Sonderfallzwei = part3 + "." + part4 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
                     bw.write (Sonderfallzwei);
                 } //close if
                 else {     
                     String part3zwei = parts[2]; //vielleicht Entfernung                           
                     String finished  = part3zwei + "." + part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
                     textnow = br.readLine();
                     bw.write(finished + n );
                     bw.flush();
                 } //close else 2       
             }//close else 1
         } //close while

         textnow = br.readLine();
         bw.flush();
         bw.close(); 
         br.close(); 

    } //close static void main String                                            
} //close class
```

Comment: There is "an error". Could you be more specific? Do understand, that when it is about logic, we don't know what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Your problem most likely is that you do this: String part3        = parts[2]; before you verify whether or not there is a third element in the array.

Comment: I'm sorry there it is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at javadruckdruckextended.main(javadruckdruckextended.java:54)

Comment: Then the problem is indeed, you are trying to get the third element from an array that only has two elements. That assignment ( = parts[2]) should only be done when verified there are at least three elements in the array

Comment: You already have that checking code commented out (`Zur Fehlerkontrolle  ...`), didn't it tell you that problem already? Btw, I'd remove/mask domains or names in code posted here (Datenschutz).

Answer (score 0):

The assignments and the length checks are clearly out of order here:

> ```
>     String part1 = parts[0];
>     String part2 = parts[1];
>     String part3 = parts[2];
>
>     if (parts.length < 2) {
>         String Sonderfalleins = part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
>         bw.write(Sonderfalleins);
>     } else {
>         if (parts.length > 3) {
>             String part4 = parts[3];
>             String Sonderfallzwei = part3 + "." + part4 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
>             bw.write(Sonderfallzwei);
>         } //close if
> ```

That is, you are referencing `parts[1]` before checking it actually exists.
If `parts.length < 2` then `parts[1]` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
The same goes for `parts[3]`.

Here's one possible simple fix:

```
    String part1 = parts[0];

    if (parts.length < 2) {
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String Sonderfalleins = part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
        bw.write(Sonderfalleins);
    } else {
        if (parts.length > 3) {
            String part3 = parts[2];
            String part4 = parts[3];
            String Sonderfallzwei = part3 + "." + part4 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
            bw.write(Sonderfallzwei);
        } //close if
```